# Inheritance over composition

Tags: oop

The benefits of using composition over inheritance are quite well known;

What are the cases in which the opposite is preferable?

Practically, I can see the advantage of forcing a base constructor, but I would like to know other people's opinion about other cases/domains.

Comment: If you can see the advantage, then you have answered your question.  You as the designer can make the decision and you will be right.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the famous recommendation of "favor composition over inheritance" was coined in the GoF Design Patterns book.

It says (p.20):

> *Favor object composition over class inheritance.*
>
> Ideally, you shouldn't have to create new components to achieve reuse.
>   You should be able to get all the functionality you need just by
>   assembling existing components through object composition. But this is
>   rarely the case, because the set of available components is never
>   quite rich enough in practice. Reuse by inheritance makes it easier to
>   make new components that can be composed with old ones. Inheritance
>   and object composition thus work together.
>
> Nevertheless, our experience is that designers overuse inheritance as
>   a reuse technique, and designs are often made more reusable (and
>   simpler) by depending more on object composition. You'll see object
>   composition applied again and again in the design patterns.

Notice that this statement refers to *class inheritance*, and must be distinguished from *interface inheritance* which is fine.

**Dynamism**

Both are ways to achieve reusability, but the advantage of composition over inheritance is dynamism. Since the composition can be changed dynamically at runtime this represents a great advantage, whereas inheritance is statically defined at compile time.

**Encapsulation**

Also, composition is based on using the public interfaces of the composed objects, therefore objects respect each other's public interfaces and therefore this fosters encapsulation. On the other hand, inheritance breaks encapsulation since child components typically consume a protected interface from the parent. It is a well known problem that changes in the parent class can break the child classes, the famous base class problem. Also in inheritance parent classes define the physical representation of subclasses, therefore child clases depend on parent classes to evolve.

**Cohesion**

Another advantage of composition is that it keeps classes focused on one task and this foster cohesion as well.

**Liabilities**

Evidently a problem with composition is that you will have more objects and fewer classes. That makes a little more difficult to visualize your design and how it achieves its goals. When debugging code it is harder to know what is going on unless you know what exact instance of a given composite is currently being used by an object. So composition makes designs a bit harder to understand in my opinion.

Since the advantages of composition are multiple that's why it is suggested to favor it over inheritance, but that does not mean inheritance is always bad. You can achieve a great deal when inheritance is properly used.

**Interesting References**

I would suggest a study of [GoF Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) to see good examples of both types of reusability, for instance a [Strategy Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) that uses composition vs a [Template Method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) that uses inheritance.

Most of the patterns make a great use of interface inheritance and then object composition to achieve their goals and only a few use class inheritance as a reusability mechanism.

If you want to delve more the book [Holub on Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001REFS14), on chapter 2 has a section called Why `extends` is Evil that delve much more on the liabilities of class inheritance.

The book mentions three specific aspects

> - **Losing Flexibility**: The first problem is that explicit use of a concrete-class name locks you into a specific implementation, making
>     down-the-line changes unnecessarily difficult.
> - **Coupling**: A more important problem with implementation inheritance is coupling, the undesirable reliance of one part of a
>     program on another part. Global variables are the classic example of
>     why strong coupling is bad. If you change the type of a global
>     variable, for example, all the code that uses that variable—that is
>     coupled to the variable—can be affected, so all this code must be
>     examined, modified, and retested. Moreover, all the methods that use
>     the variable are coupled to each other through the variable. That is,
>     one method may incorrectly affect the behavior of another method
>     simply by changing the variable’s value at an awkward time. This
>     problem is particularly hideous in multithreaded programs.
> - **Fragile-Base-Class Problem**: In an implementation-inheritance system (one that uses extends), the derived classes are tightly
>     coupled to the base classes, and this close connection is undesirable.
>     Designers have applied the moniker “the fragile-base-class problem” to
>     describe this behavior. Base classes are considered “fragile” because
>     you can modify a base class in a seemingly safe way, but this new
>     behavior, when inherited by the derived classes, may cause the derived
>     classes to malfunction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I agree with all your points, but I was looking for something more focused on the pros of the inheritance as I'm already familiar with the advantages of the composition. I also agree that inheritance makes the design more clear, but I don't think it is enough to choose that approach.

Answer (score 2):

The only advantage of inheritance over composition that I can think of is that it can potentially save you from a lot of boiler plate method delegation.

If you truly have an is-a relationship *and* you simply want all the methods from a base class in your subclass, then inheritance gives you all those methods for free.

Comment: In some programming languages like Go a regular composition does that too. All for free.

Answer (score 0):

It's a complete debatable or argumentation question and broad as well.

AFAIK, when we talk about containership (or) something containing another thing we go for `Composition`; i.e, An entity contains another entity; which also gives a `HAS A` relationship. Example: `EntityA` has a `EntityB`.
See `Decorator design pattern`, which is based on the concept of `Composition`.

But when we talk about `Inheritance` we talk about `IS A` relationship. i.e, `EntityA` Is A `EntityB` (or) `EntityA` Is type of a `EntityB`

Answer (score 0):

One special case when I find inheritance the best solution is when I use a runtime-generated class that need additional methods. For example (in C#):

```cs
public abstract class Rule{
    /* properties here */
    public Authorization Authorization { get; set; }
    public abstract bool IsValid(dynamic request, User currentUser);
}
```

The generated template:

```cs
public class Generated_1Rule : Rule{
    public override bool IsValid(dynamic request, User currentUser){
        // the user script is here
    }
}
```

Example of user script:

```cs
return Authorization.IsAuthorized("Module_ID_001", currentUser);
```

The benefit is that you can add functionality to the generated script “compiled-ly”, and it’s less breaking than inheriting from interface / composition since it is compiled.